# JSF set string into IMG tag (src="")

Tags: html, jsf, facelets

I am trying to figured out this situation. I would like to put an image name into html tag but i don't know how to fill it. I am using Java Server Faces 2.0 .

here is sample of my code:

```
<img src="the\path\to\my\files\'#{manageBean.fileName}'" />
```

result of this : 
`<img src="the\path\to\my\files\'fileName.suffix'` />

Not working : Image does not display !

Is there any better way which my brain missing ? Thanks to all for answer and suggestions.

Comment: The quotation marks which cover the filename. The image doesnt display becouse them i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that I see.

- First, you don't need the single quotes around `#{managedBean.fileName}`, so you can just leave them out.
- Second, you may want to use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Lastly, you may want to take a look at the documentation for the `<h:graphicImage>` tag.  It may or may not be overkill for what you're trying to do.  There are lots of examples to be found out there, though.

Comment: if I remove the single quotes it will represent this as a string so the output is .... \files\'#{manageBean.fileName}' . I also tried to put there forward slashes with correct file name and it was recognized. I am going to find another way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: As its too late today I am getting dumper. Your first suggestion works fine. I had to do something wrong. Thank you.. SOLVED

Comment: Thanks.  If that works for you, would you mind accepting the answer?